# Where can I find the source code for "reboot" command?

Tags: linux, command, reboot

From where to get the source code for `reboot` command in Linux ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [shutdown.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=utils/util-linux/util-linux-ng.git;a=blob;f=simpleinit/shutdown.c;hb=HEAD) in [util-linux](http://userweb.kernel.org/~kzak/util-linux/).

Comment: At least on Scientific Linux, this one is the source for /sbin/shutdown cmd, not /sbin/reboot. The other answer using rpm -qf is better for me.

Answer (score 2):

On RHEL / CentOS at least it's in the SysVinit package. You can determine this by

```
which reboot
```

to find the executable - it's in /sbin/reboot for me - then

```
rpm -qf /sbin/reboot
```

to find out which package it is in. You should then be able to download a SRPM from any CentOS mirror, e.g. http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/mirror.centos.org/5.5/os/SRPMS/

Comment: Along those lines, `dpkg -S /sbin/reboot` queries the owner package on dpkg-based systems, which happens to be `upstart` on Ubuntu and `sysvinit` on Debian; `apt-get source` will fetch the sources.  Too bad there isn't any single init system on Linux; each distribution has their own copy.  (Even the multiple systems named sysvinit aren't the same.)